# Why cant I rewrite a .txt file in C language?

Tags: c, file

I am trying to do this exercise in C that requires me to replace contents of a .txt file with a number that is representing how many times a certain char sequence can be found in a file.

The sequence is hello. Caps doesnt matter.

text1.txt --> grow in clusters hanging from the top of the plant. Almost all modern edible seedless BANANAS comvated bananas are Musa acuminata, Musa balbisianaX paadisiaca, depending on their genomic constitution.

text2.txt --> In the past, there was a hoax that some countries wanted to ban ananas (also known as pineaause it was less delicious than bananas but fortunately, this ot true.

So with the first file, the code should rewrite it to 5 (ananas occures 5 times). In the second file there should be 2.

But when I run the program no files change.

Comment: The overall design of this code does not look good at all. But anyway: you need to check if  `fopen` fails.

Comment: it does open becouse if I put the fputc() outside of the if(){} it puts it in the file instead of the first letter of the text. Could you also tell me how to improve the design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coding need some fixes. In particular

- The construct `if(ch== 'A' || 'a'){` is incorrect. You want to use `if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'a'))`
- Always check for fopen for NULL
- Modify 1st fopen to "r" mode, modify 2nd fopen to "w" mode.

From coding point of view, you might want to change the logic to reduce the level of nesting.

```
   while ( ch != EOF ) {
      ch = fgetc(fp);
      if(ch != 'A' && ch != 'a') continue ;
      ch = fgets(fp) ;
      if ( ch !- 'N' && ch != 'n' ) continue ;
      ...
      counter++ ;
   } ;
```

You indicated that the problem must be solved using a small set of the standard functions. Not clear, if you are allowed to use array. If you do, you can get more elegant solutions.

Comment: Just as an explanation of why `if(ch== 'A' || 'a')` is wrong: The right side of the logical OR expression will always evaluate to true, because it is always non-zero, so that the whole expression will always evaluate to true, irrespective of the value of `ch`.

Comment: i fixed it thank you. I dont know why I didint reliase that I worked with || multiple times. Anyway it still replaces just the 1st letter. I guess im not sure how replacing files actually works

Comment: To REPLACE the complete file, modify the 2nd open to fopen(..., "w"). Also, the first should be fopen(..., "r").. Remember to make backup of your data before running the program !

Comment: I can use array and I would be very interested in how

Comment: See Alternate solution, based on array. There are library functions (e.g., strcasestr), which can make help solve this problem. Not sure if those can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Solution using arrays, sticking to single character IO.

The pattern can be set as a string (char array). With 'p' pointing to the next character to match.

```
   char pattern = "ananas" ;

   int p = 0;
   for ( char ch = fgetc(fp) ; ch != EOF ; ch = fgetc(fp)) {
       if ( isupper(ch) ) ch = tolower(ch) ;
       if ( ch != pattern[p] ) {
           p = 0 ;
           continue ;
       } ;
       p++;
       if ( pattern[p] == '\0' ) {
           // Complete Match
           counter++ ;
           p = 0 ;
       } ;
   } ;
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote: According to the text of the question, `tolower()` is not allowed. However, I see no clean way to not use this function, except by implementing the function yourself using ASCII table arithmetic.

Comment: This solution actually contains a bug in that it won't find a match in the string "anananas". However, since the text of the question disallows usage of the function `ungetc()` and the guaranteed size of the pushback buffer is only 1 byte, I see no clean way to fix this bug, except by implementing a pushback buffer yourself or by using an intermediate buffer.

Comment: For the question of partial match - especially with a pattern like 'ananas'- I think that whoever gave the assignment wanted the students to think about this issue by themselves. I suggest leaving it to the OP to try to address this weakness, and to qualify for extra score/grade.

Comment: It is possible to remove the code duplication `ch = fgetc(fp)`, by changing the for loop to an infinite for loop `for (;;)` and writing `ch = fgetc(fp); if ( ch == EOF) break;` at the start of the loop. I personally prefer to remove the code duplication, but some people prefer a bit of code duplication if that means that the infinite loop and `break` can be omitted.